# Command not found Error (stderr) while comparing string in Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

Problem is to read one character from the user (this may be `'Y', 'y', 'N', 'n'`). If the character is `Y` or `y` display `YES`. If the character is `N` or `n` display `NO`.

[**Original Problem**](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bash-tutorials---getting-started-with-conditionals)

**Here's my code:**

```
read option
if ["$option"=="y"] || ["$option"=="Y"]
then
    echo "YES"
else
    echo "NO"
fi
```

It throws  an **Error** `(stderr)`

```
solution.sh: line 2: [Y=y]: command not found
solution.sh: line 2: [Y=Y]: command not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
read option
if [ "$option" == "y" ] || [ "$option" == "Y" ]
then
echo "YES"
elif [ "$option" == "n" ] || [ "$option" == "N" ]   
then
echo "NO"
else
echo "?"
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

Leave space before `]` and after `[` in if statement.. `if [ "$option"="y" ] ||   [ "$option"="Y" ]`

Comment: Throws an error 
`line 2: [: missing `]'`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this in BASH:

```
[[ "$option" == [Yy] ]] && echo "YES" || echo "NO"
```